# DataContext connects to database, but table references are null. Why?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, azure-sql-database

I've created a data context class:

```
public class DBContextZProdDomainSS : DataContext
{
        public Table<ZTask> ZTasks { get; set; }
        public Table<ZProject> ZProjects { get; set; }
        public Table<ZUser> ZUsers { get; set; }

        public DBContextZProdDomainSS() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZProdDomainSS"].ConnectionString) { }
}
```

It successfully connects to the database when it is instantiated like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ZTask> ZTaskRead()
{
    using (var context = new DBContextZProdDomainSS())
    {
        if (context.DatabaseExists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found database");
        }

        return context.ZTasks.ToList();
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, the method `context.DatabaseExists()` returns true, but when I step through and check the value of the connection it says closed. Also, all the table references are null even though it says the database exists.

Here's an example of my connection string (with sensitive info removed):

```
Server=tcp:zproductivity.database.windows.net,1433;
     Initial Catalog=ZProdDomainSS;Persist Security Info=False;
     User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
     Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

But for whatever reason, the table references are all null. Why is this happening? I've gone through each of my model classes and mapped them like so:

```
    [Table(Name = "ZTasks")]
    public class ZTask : ModelBase
    {
        #region props
        [Column(Name = "ZID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public long ZID { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "UtcCreatedDateTime", IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public DateTime UtcCreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "Title", CanBeNull = true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "ZUserZID", CanBeNull = false)]
        public long ZUserZID { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "Description", CanBeNull = true)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "ZProjectZID", CanBeNull =true)]
        public long? ZProjectZID { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "ZParentTaskZID", CanBeNull = true)]
        public long? ZParentTaskZID { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "UtcDueDate", CanBeNull = true)]
        public DateTime? UtcDueDate { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "UtcCompletionDateTime", CanBeNull = true)]
        public DateTime? UtcCompletionDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "Completed", CanBeNull = false)]
        public bool Completed { get; set; }
    }
```

Both ZProjects and ZUsers are mapped in the same way. Here's the database schema for ZTasks:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZTasks] 
(
    [ZID]                   BIGINT         IDENTITY (100000000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]                 NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ZUserZID]              BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [Description]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ZProjectZID]           BIGINT         NULL,
    [UtcDueDate]            DATETIME       DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [UtcCompletionDateTime] DATETIME       DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [Completed]             BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [UtcCreatedDateTime]    DATETIME       DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
    [ZParentTaskZID]        BIGINT         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ZTasks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ZID] ASC)
);
```

Why are the table references null? How can I fix this?

Comment: I‘m not sure if I‘m right but I‘ve never seen `Table<foo>` as property in a db context. I always use `DbSet<foo>` Why do you use `DataContext` instead of `DbContext`?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use LINQ-to-SQL. It was great, but now it's obsolete. Use Entity Framework instead.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. I'll do that. I had previously been using EF, but ran into problems managing migrations and wanted the freedom to modify the database and my model classes independently.